# Install debian dependecies for git source project

Tags: navigation, rosdep, git, source, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i have all my source for my custom robot on github, and i only want to have my own custom source in there. I have been looking around everywhere, and am trying to figure out how to make these steps below work:

- A member from my team does fresh linux install
- installs ros full desktop indigo through apt-get
- creates a catkin workspace, and does "git clone [repo url] src"

Now he needs to compile the source, but because he just did a clean install, packages (dependencies in this case) like robot_localization, move_base_msgs, etc, are not installed to his system yet.

What i am trying to figure out is how can i set it up so that when he downloads/compiles the source, the respective *debian* package dependencies are installed in the easiest way possible (to /opt/ros/indigo). Im trying to minimize the least amount of commands since the new guys in my club are just learning ROS. Since they do not know yet what robot_localization or move_base_msgs is yet, im trying to eliminate having them take additional steps in order to just get our gazebo model with ros plugins, robot_localization, move_base, etc... to start up.

Ive looked at a few packages at tried to see how they do it, but i only found in clearpaths jackal repo that they had a rosinstall file. Someone please correct me if i am wrong: I do not think i want to do rosinstall because it seems as if rosinstall installs the source; looking inside the rosinstall for jackal, it is listing github urls, and branches which is not what i am trying to do)

I obviously tried using rosdep, but it seems like you can only invoke things like "rosdep check [package/stack]" if the package is in the /opt/ros/[distro]/ path. I tried to do it from my catkin workspace (since that was one of the 4 paths rosdep error was giving) and it still didnt work:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource simulation/scipio_simulation/
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/l0g1x/edt/l0g1x_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

So then i tried to add install() to the CMakeLists.txt of one of my packages (so that i can then call rosdep check/install/etc. on it) by adding:

```
install(DIRECTORY launch/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.launch"
  PATTERN ".git" EXCLUDE)
```

But then i couldnt build the package because catkin picked up that robot_localization was not installed (i listed it as my packages dependency in the CMakeLists.txt in the package() line), so it would not install to the /opt/ros/indigo folder..

Does anybody have any insight on what i should do or how to go about this to make the process of setting up our project as seamless as possible for a new member of my club?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried this command as well from my catkin_ws/ folder:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
```

And i think this does the trick.. Can someone confirm this is the CORRECT way to do what i am trying to do? Dont want to learn bad habits

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197542/install-debian-dependecies-for-git-source-project/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the command you posted is the right thing to do in this case. It allows `rosdep` to figure out what packages are either not installed from `apt-get` nor in the current workspace and then try to install those from `apt-get`.

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
```

The `--from-paths src` option tells `rosdep` to resolve dependencies for packages found in that folder, `src`, and the `--ignore-src` option tells `rosdep` not to try and install packages it finds in the folders given to `--from-paths`, in this case `src`. Without this option you get something like the error you got above which resulted because `rosdep` saw that `scipio_simulation` was a dependency of some other package so it would try to resolve it (check that it is installed else install it), but since it is not released `rosdep` cannot handle it and bails out.

One note is that you should do this:

```
$ mkdir -p /path/to/workspace/src
$ cd /path/to/workspace/src
$ git clone [url]
```

Rather than cloning the repo directly as `src`, as you suggested:

> creates a catkin workspace, and does
> "git clone [repo url] src"

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thanks william. The reason i did git clone [url] src was because if you dont specify a folder at the end of the git command, it creates a folder under the name of the repo: `/workspace/src/edt_software/`. Is there a REP on this workspace structure?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-18**:
Sure: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html#workspace